# The parent div is not expanding with the child divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
}

.headerspan {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #009EE3;
  border-bottom: thick solid #F39200;
}

.headercontainer {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

.phonenumber {
  text-align: center;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.responsiveimg {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="headerspan">
    <div class="headercontainer">
      <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_6_of_12">
          <img class="responsiveimg" src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col span_6_of_12 phonenumber">
          Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

The text in the final child div overflows, and the parent does not expand. Could anyone shed some light on this? Thank you.

[image: Image of the current output in a browser]

Comment: `height: 2em;` remove this

Comment: D'oh. That was simple - I've been staring at it for hours. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `height:2em;` to `min-height:2em;` for `.phonenumber`

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
}

.headerspan {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #009EE3;
  border-bottom: thick solid #F39200;
}

.headercontainer {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

.phonenumber {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.responsiveimg {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="headerspan">
    <div class="headercontainer">
      <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_6_of_12">
          <img class="responsiveimg" src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col span_6_of_12 phonenumber">
          Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```